# Suppressing "Nullable value type may be null" warnings for method taking array of tuples?

Tags: c#, nullable

I have a method that takes an array of tuples of two Vector3's [System.Numerics], and if the 2nd item of any tuple is null, it calculates a value for that and fills it in:

*** EDIT - thanks to comments from @Adam, @madreflection and @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace, I've tweaked the sample code below, which is a cut-down version of the real thing (and previously badly done so - apologies) ***

```
public static bool CalculateMissingStuff((Vector3, Vector3?)[] vertices)
{
    for (var vertexIndex = 0; vertexIndex < vertices.Length; vertexIndex++)
    {
        if (vertices[vertexIndex].Item2 == null)
        {
            // Compute value here using vertices[vertexIndex].Item1:
            vertices[vertexIndex].Item2 = ...
        ...
```

If it fails to calculate and assign a value for any Item2, the return value is false, otherwise it's true.

All well and good so far, but in the calling code, upon dereferencing an array element's Item2 having called the above method, a warning is generated saying the nullable type may be null. I'm looking for a way to suppress those warnings. At this point in the calling code I've already tested the return value and bailed out if false.

Is there any way of specifying that when my CalculateMissingStuff method returns true, none of the Item2 values in the array can be null? I'm thinking along the lines of attributes like "NotNullWhen" etc. in the method header, but I can't get my head around the syntax in this case, partly because I'm inexperienced with method attributes, but maybe it's not possible with tuple members.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: If I remember correctly, tuples are immutable, meaning changes you do in your function will not affect the values passed by your calling function. If you want the null replaced, you need to encapsulate within a class or change the return of your function to include modified vertices in the return.

Comment: When it can't be null why do you say it can be null? You wrote `Vector3?`. And like @Adam suggest i can't see this working in the first place.

Comment: The array is not immutable, though, so you can assign the tuple back with `vertices[vertextIndex] = vertex;` and the caller will observe the change. Nevertheless, the compiler can't see into this method to know that the nulls have been replaced with values. If the caller can be absolutely certain that this has been done, use the null-forgiveness operator.

Comment: Correction to the 1st comment: C# tuples are of course mutable, it's just that C# tuples are value types (structs), therefore `vertex.Item2 = ...` will not alter an element in the array, because vertex is only a _copy_ of vertices[vertexIndex]. Also possibly noteworthy: Do not confuse C# tuples with the System.Tuple<...> type, they are different things...

Comment: Another thing you could do is return `(Vector3, Vector3)[]`, a copy of the array without the nullable tuple item. This may not perform as you want, though, since it involves a new array allocation, and the time to copy all the elements to the new array as you fill in what's missing.

Comment: If OP sets `vertices[vertexIndex] = vertex` at the end of the loop, then the result will be returned to the caller. With the function as-is, it will not modify the tuples within the array.

Comment: You can't guarantee that Item2  is not null after the method in a way that the compiler will believe even when you get working code to change the array. Have you thought about how your tuple array looks if there is an exception while iterating over it? One way would be the suggestion @madreflection gives on returning a new tuple. But returning a tuple (bool, vertices tuple) is crazy. Try to get rid of the tuple.

Comment: The actual method from which my (badly) edited code snippet derives does work, by the way; it really does fill in values for all Item2's that are missing them in the original array. Could the confusion/disagreement here be because the Vector3 items are structs? In any case, that is a distraction from the point of my question.

Comment: Distractions aside, you've been given real suggestions. As far as an *answer*, it's going to be difficult to write an *acceptable* answer since the question is a bit broad and doesn't include enough information to align it with your design needs (such as how much you can or want to alter your current design).

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace For anyone confused why the code actually works: Arrays (just like Spans) don't use `T this[int index] { get { ... } set { ... } }` type of indexer, they use `ref T this[int index] { get { ... } }` type of indexer. Arrays and Spans return references to their elements, not copies. `vertices[vertexIndex]` is actually `ref (Vector3, Vector3?)`, not a copy, so that's why `vertices[vertexIndex].Item2 = ...` works

Comment: @Petrusion my comment and those of others were prior to an edit of the question that altered the code example. Check the edit history of the question to see the original question version my comment was about...

Comment: Thanks to all for the suggestions. To summarise, it would seem that it is not possible to achieve what I want in the way I want it, so my remaining options look like either to put up with the status quo (optionally with null forgiveness) or else redesign the method interface and by implication the calling code, too.